# The page at https://example.com was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image http://example.com

Tags: asp.net, web, umbraco

I see this error on my site while loading in Chrome. But it does not mention which specific image it is looking for

The page at https://example.com was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image http://example.com

Can I have some suggestions how to find what is loaded on HTTP. I tried various plugins on Chrome, but none of them were able to figure out the HTTP URL.

Comment: In the Chrome developer tools, the network panel should show you all of the requests made.

Comment: Press F12 in the browser.

Comment: Surprisingly I don't see anything in network tab. On security Tab, it shows one request in non-secure origins. When I click on that it goes to network tab and shows me one request which is the domain name listed in http and 301 to https.

Answer (score 0):

Able to find the issue and solve it. Scenario was bit tricky. There was one image at 
http://example.com/css/images/def.png which is referenced in one of the files. And there was a redirect rule for this image / path to redirect to home page. I had to delete the redirect rule. Once deleted, I dont see the mixed content error now.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: How did I find the url is important to share - when I clicked on the error on security tab, it took me to Network tab and able to find this image URL there.